# Why isn't the IgnoreDataMember attribute working when returning json from mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm returning a JsonResult from an MVC controller action , and have been trying to remove one attribute but not having much joy.

```
return Json(db.Pages.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I have tried decorating my class that is being returned with the

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
```

attribute, and using [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes on other attributes on the class but this seems to be ignored.

I found a post here where it states that returning json in this way will use that JavaScriptSerializer, I tried using [ScriptIgnore] but vs2010 doesn't recognise this as a valid attribute. http://teamezy.blogspot.com/2008/12/making-jsonresult-in-mvc-ignore.html

Do I need to return data in a different way in order for the IgnoreDataMember or DataContract / DataMember stuff to work?

Comment: `Json` / `JsonResult` uses `JavaScriptSerializer`, not `DataContractJsonSerializer`; `IgnoreDataMember`, `DataContract` and `DataMember` are irrelevant. See Jon's answer for what *does* matter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`ScriptIgnoreAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) is in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace - do you have an appropriate `using` directive and reference to the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly?

Remember to set `ProxyCreationEnabled` to false.

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```